# How to determine what % of variance is due to noise (with limited data)

Tags: variance, standard-deviation, signal-detection, noise

this is a difficult question and perhaps not answerable without further data.

I have a list of staff that get monthly scores that are averages of customer ratings. (95%, 75%, 89%)

So, the most granular data I have, is each individual rating score from customers for each individual staff.

My question is -- how do I determine what % of that score is either noise, or outside the scope of the variable (individual's name).

Let's get down to brass tacks. Of office has an overall satisfaction rating. Say one month it's 80% ---- the next month it's 81%, or 79%.

Some colleagues are really putting a lot of stock in these tiny needle moves. Moves that are quite possibly --- just noise variance and are ultimately meaningless. But, at what point due we separate noise from true movement?

Would I be looking at standard deviation of the individual scores, or the aggregate monthly scores? Hmm for some reason I just don't know where to begin here.

Comment: Where are the individual staff ratings coming from? Online surveys of customer service? How often are customers polled? And is it the same number of times per month for everyone? Are the individual ratings composites of several different attributes or factors? Do you know how the individual ratings are aggregated to create a total rating for the office?

Comment: Yes, it's an online survey. So I know there is obviously some self-selection bias, but at least this should remain consistent month to month. Customers are polled after interacting with our customer service immediately, so basically every day. # ratings are not the same for everyone as people handle different amounts of interactions. The score is a composite of 5 equal questions -- but let's assume it's just one overall score -- tackling potential correlations and proper weighting of those is another matter. Aggregation of the office score is simply the average of every single survey.

Comment: So, if you have 50 reps each getting 5 customer ratings per day...you would have about 250 surveys per office per day, correct? I would go with averaging the individual scores and producing the standard deviation around that average on a daily basis. The 68–95–99.7 rule in statistics stipulates that, if your data is normally distributed, then 68% of it will fall within +/- 1 std dev., 95% will fall within +/- 2 std devs and 99.7% of it will fall within 3 std devs. -- see Wikipedia entry. Statistically different days would occur when the std dev is about 2 std devs plus from the mean.

Comment: That makes sense -- could I do the same with the monthly aggregation, however? And again the question is tough because the true mean may be moving.

Comment: Now you're getting into questions concerned with any trends, seasonality or periodicity to the ratings, for instance, month and quarter of the year issues, ratings growth, etc.. Needless to say, that's a bit more complicated.